# Async Programming In Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous

Im trying to use async task in my windows form project but im stuck right now. My problem is writing data into richtextbox. I have 48800 lines into a list and while it prints to richtextbox, everything stops. I can't close form until it finishes. I wrote this code but nothing changed.

## BUTTON CLICK

```
private async void B_fullData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            var outputBox = form2.GetTextBox();
            await printFullData(lines, outputBox);              
        }
```

## PRINT

```
private async Task printFullData(List<Entry> input, RichTextBox textBox)
        {            
            foreach (var line in input)
            {
               textBox.AppendText(line);                   
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use a StringBuilder and only *one* AppendText() call.

Comment: So where are you _actually_ using async/await?

Comment: async/await should be used for I/O based calls where completion ports are used. Like writing to a file, reading from a database, sending network traffic, etc. If you want to offload some CPU bound operation then you should use a background worker. That said you should probably first figure out *why* your code is slow by debugging it and seeing if you can optimize it (re write it) to not be slow. (see `Hans Passant` comment, that would probably fix your problem).

Comment: @HansPassant you should make that an answer before someone else gives a _really bad_ answer that OP accepts.

Comment: `printFullData` doesn't perform any asynchronous operations.  Surely there's a compiler warning about this.

Comment: The message pump is probably being flooded because of the loop. You should update the richtextbox every second with the full appended string from the stringbuilder. This way you'll keep the UI responsive